# Get type name without full namespace

Tags: c#, namespaces, typeof

I have the following code:

```
return "[Inserted new " + typeof(T).ToString() + "]";
```

But

```
 typeof(T).ToString()
```

returns the full name including namespace

Is there anyway to just get the class name (without any namespace qualifiers?)

Comment: Incidentally, writing `string1 + anything.ToString() + string2` is redundant. The compiler inserts the call to `ToString` automatically if you do `string1 + anything + string2`.

Comment: not to sound harsh but, had you inspected what properties are available on the `Type` instance (as returned by `typeof(..)`) I'm pretty sure you'd figure out this yourself...

Comment: For some reason the `Name` property is missing from the documentation - at least, it's not where I was looking for it.

Comment: @MichaelKay `Name` is member of `MemberInfo` which is base class of `Type`.

Answer (score 668, accepted):

```
typeof(T).Name // class name, no namespace
typeof(T).FullName // namespace and class name
typeof(T).Namespace // namespace, no class name
```

Comment: `Name` doesn't consider type parameters.

Comment: Or `this.GetType().Name`, `this.GetType().FullName`, etc. if dealing with instances.

Comment: `Name` also doesn't consider nested types!

Answer (score 42):

Try this to get type parameters for generic types:

```
public static string CSharpName(this Type type)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    var name = type.Name;
    if (!type.IsGenericType) return name;
    sb.Append(name.Substring(0, name.IndexOf('`')));
    sb.Append("<");
    sb.Append(string.Join(", ", type.GetGenericArguments()
                                    .Select(t => t.CSharpName())));
    sb.Append(">");
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Maybe not the best solution (due to the recursion), but it works.  Outputs look like:

```
Dictionary<String, Object>
```

Comment: This ought to be the accepted answer as it properly takes into consideration generic types which may recurse (Dictionary<int?,int?> for instance).

Comment: +1 for the concept. But dislike the failed premature optimisation. It creates a **new** `StringBuilder` in each recursive call (even the base case when it's unused), yet ignores the `string.Join` temporary and LINQ lambda. Just use `String` until you _know_ it's a bottleneck. /rant

Comment: Nigel, it says right there that's is probably not the best solution :)

Comment: ShortName is a shorter name :)

Comment: While the update is appreciated, this was answered almost a decade ago.  I've used updated versions in my own code since.  (Maybe I should have updated here.)

Answer (score 12):

make use of ([Type Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type_properties.aspx))

```
 Name   Gets the name of the current member. (Inherited from MemberInfo.)
 Example : typeof(T).Name;
```

Answer (score 10):

After the C# 6.0 (including) you can use [nameof](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986596.aspx) expression:

```
using Stuff = Some.Cool.Functionality  
class C {  
    static int Method1 (string x, int y) {}  
    static int Method1 (string x, string y) {}  
    int Method2 (int z) {}  
    string f<T>() => nameof(T);  
}  

var c = new C()  

nameof(C) -> "C"  
nameof(C.Method1) -> "Method1"   
nameof(C.Method2) -> "Method2"  
nameof(c.Method1) -> "Method1"   
nameof(c.Method2) -> "Method2"  
nameof(z) -> "z" // inside of Method2 ok, inside Method1 is a compiler error  
nameof(Stuff) = "Stuff"  
nameof(T) -> "T" // works inside of method but not in attributes on the method  
nameof(f) -> “f”  
nameof(f<T>) -> syntax error  
nameof(f<>) -> syntax error  
nameof(Method2()) -> error “This expression does not have a name”
```

Note! `nameof` not get the underlying object's runtime Type, it is just the compile-time argument. If a method accepts an IEnumerable then nameof simply returns "IEnumerable", whereas the actual object could be "List".

Comment: `nameof` does not return the name of the `Type`

Comment: @NigelTouch I've checked and `nameof` return the name of the `Type`, screenshot with proof: http://prntscr.com/irfk2c

Comment: Sorry, I didn't explain well. What I mean is that it does not get the underlying object's runtime `Type`, it is just the compile-time argument. If a method accepts an `IEnumerable` then `nameof` simply returns "IEnumerable", whereas the actual object could be "List<string>". It don't think it answers the OP's question.

Answer (score 9):

you can do this:

```
typeof(T).Name;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `Type.Name` property to get just the class name without the namespace qualifiers.

```
return "[Inserted new " + typeof(T).Name + "]";
```