# C# equivalent of class.forName() in Java

Tags: c#, class

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get type name without full namespace in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3396300/get-type-name-without-full-namespace-in-c-sharp)

Does anybody know how we can get the name of a class in a simple way like what Java can do via `class.getName()` ?

NB: Yes, there are some messy workaround like `CreateInstance` of the class type and then get the name of object but I want a simple way.

Edit 1:

Actually, I need the class name in a method say X. Meanwhile, I don't want to loose type-safety and I'm not gonna allow other developers to pass a string to the method. Something like this:

```
void X( ??? class) // --> don't know how
{
     var className = get the name of class // --> which I don't know how
     Console.WriteLine(className);
}

X(tblEmployee); //--> usage of X, where tblEmployee is a POCO class
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You mean, like this?

```
typeof(YourClass).Name
```

To clarify, in .NET framework there's a class named `Type`. This class has a property named `Name` that retrieves the name of the class.

So, to retrieve the Type of a class in compile time you can use `typeof`.

```
var typeName = typeof(YourClass).Name
```

If you doesn't know the type at runtime, you can retrieve it with the `GetType()` method. This is common for all .NET objects.

```
Animal a = new Dog();
var typeName = a.GetType().Name;
```

**Answer for Edit 1**

You need to pass a `Type` parameter

```
void X(Type classType) 
{
     var className = classType.Name;
     Console.WriteLine(className);
}
```

And a call to `X` should be like this

```
X(typeof(YourClass));
```

or

```
X(YourInstance.GetType());
```

Answer (score 1):

If `class` is

- instance of some type:

  ```
  class.GetType().Name;
  class.GetType().FullName; // with namespace
  ```
- type itself:

  ```
  typeof(class).Name;
  typeof(class).Name; // with namespace
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
typeof(YourClass).FullName;
```