# How to get the Full Type Name of an object

Tags: vb.net

I want to get the full name of an object declared. The following method do not give me what I want:

```
Dim objTemp As System.Int32

Debug.Print(TypeName(objTemp))
```

The result is `Integer`, I want to have is as declared `System.Int32`

Comment: Firstly, you don't declare objects. You declare variables and assign objects to them.

Comment: Console.WriteLine(objTemp.GetType())

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get type name without full namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3396300/get-type-name-without-full-namespace)

Comment: TypeName() is a vb.net-specific helper function that speaks with a basic lisp.  It behaves the way it did in previous Basic versions, [like VBA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/typename-function).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**GetType()** returns only 1 level when **GetType().FullName** gives you the entire mapping including the assembly.

```
Dim objTemp As System.Int32

Debug.Print(objTemp.GetType().FullName)
```

Comment: Please mark this as the correct answer if that's the result expected. Thanks!

Comment: Could you please add details to your proposed answer as to why the OP was getting an `Integer` instead of `System.Int32`.

Answer (score 0):

Use GetType.ToString

```
objTemp.GetType.ToString
```